# Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "--" from accessing a frame with origin "--"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, cross-domain

I want to provide a gadget type calculator plugin service to my client websites. This will add a button that will popup a calculator from my own website and its calculated result will be posted to my corresponding client's website.

I am using code from here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-value-from-child-popup-window-to-parent-page-window-using-JavaScript.aspx to post the selected content of popup window to its opener window. Its working great in IE but due to security issues Google Chrome is showing error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "--my website's domain--" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "--my client website's domain--". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I know why this error is coming, but is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You can use jsonp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: Between frames or popups you should use the [`postMessage` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)